# How many round of Madness before it end?

Tags: watch-dogs

Since I've recently ended Watch_Dog and already collected almost all of the collectables, I started to do the different Digital Trips.

Ending Conspiracy and Spider Tank, I unlocked two exclusive outfit, but now I'm trying to end Madness.

There is no save-point, no sign I'm going further and at round 27 I still didn't unlocked anything.

Granted, I'm far from completing the skill tree, which needed to be completed to see the end of Conspiracy and Spider Tank.

So basically:

What are the condition of victory in Madness Digital Trip? What is the reward in completing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Madness ends after Phase 29. If you complete it, you get a victory screen and a new outfit.

Comment: A good idea when answering is to post a source or proof.

Answer (score -1):

It might seem like an excessive amount since you're only driving into demons, but there are 29 phases.